# In a proof question, can I substitute $P(A \cup B)$ into $P(A) + P(B)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The full question is:

> If $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive events and $P(B) > 0$, show that
>   $$P(A\mid A \cup B) = \frac{P(A)}{P(A) + P(B)}$$

Since the full equation for $P(A \cup B)$ is $P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$, but I think that if they put $P(A) + P(B)$, they're implying it's $P(A \cup B)$ and thus I can sub it in the RHS.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are asking, but if $A,B$ are mutually exclusive then $P(A\cap B)=0$ (by definition).

Comment: Ok, I hadn't thought of that. But say that A and B weren't mutually exclusive, then I can't sub it in right?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: To repeat, though:  I don't understand the statement you call the "full question".    Perhaps you mistyped that?

Comment: I put in there to put some context. Your comment is what I was looking for, cause I want to do the proof myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive, hence $P(A \cap B)=0$.

$$P( A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)=P(A)+P(B)$$

so you can replace $P(A)+P(B)$ by $P(A \cup B)$ since they are equal.

Remark: The quesiton looks strange to me, did you miss a division sign?

Comment: Totally. Nice catch

Comment: In the asked for equation we also use $A \cap (A \cup B)  =A$ for the upper term in the definition $P(C|D) = \frac{P(C \cap D)}{P(D)}$ provided $P(D) > 0$.